# Angular radio validation in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to create a form that is valid if a radio button is selected. The radio button is part of a group from which the user can choose one.  I'm assigning the `required` attribute to the radio buttons using a function in my controller, and this seems to be causing issues with the validation.  I think it's some sort of scope problem but I can't figure it out.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/x27nv8fq/5/

You can see that the radio inputs correctly have the `required` attribute assigned to them, but even if the user doesn't select an option, the form still validates and submits.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestController">
    <form name="testForm" ng-submit="testForm.$valid && submitForm()" novalidate>
        <div ng-repeat="option in options">
            <input type="radio" name="testInput" 
                ng-value="option" 
                ng-model="$parent.selectedOption" 
                ng-required="required()" />
            {{ option.value }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <p ng-show="testForm.testInput.$invalid">Form is invalid</p>
        {{ selectedOption }}
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.options = [{id: '0', value: 'blue'}, {id: 1, value: 'green'}]
    $scope.selectedOption = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function(){
         alert('Form valid and submitted');   
    }

    $scope.required = function(){
        if(!$scope.selectedOption.id){
            return true;   
        }

        return false;
    }
}]);
```

Why is the form considered valid even though a `required` radio input is not selected?

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 issues that I noticed:

1)  The $scope.selectedOption (as you mentioned)
2)  The $scope.required function is unnecessary as far as I can tell.  You should just set required to true on those inputs - Angular knows via the name attribute that only 1 of the inputs needs to be checked.

You can see it in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/x27nv8fq/6/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestController">
    <form name="testForm" ng-submit="testForm.$valid && submitForm()" novalidate>
        <div ng-repeat="option in options">
            <input type="radio" name="testInput" 
                ng-value="option" 
                ng-model="selectedOption" 
                ng-required="true" />
            {{ option.value }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <p ng-show="testForm.testInput.$invalid">Form is invalid</p>
        {{ selectedOption }}
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.options = [{id: '0', value: 'blue'}, {id: 1, value: 'green'}]
    $scope.selectedOption;

    $scope.submitForm = function(){
         alert('Form valid and submitted');   
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that I'm initializing `$scope.selectedOption` to `{}` rather than leaving it undefined. I'm guessing that since an empty object is "truthy", Angular considers it valid.  Remove this from the code seems to have fixed the problem.